# My terminology question seems to fit the on-topic conditions, but I was downvoted and linked to meta. Explanation (please)?

Tags: discussion

terminology tag (as defined by you guys):

> Questions about the objective meaning or 
>      common understanding of words and 
>      concepts that programmers encounter.

Well I need to develop something which reads audio data to be played, and [I asked what one calls the term for the "rate" at which audio is interpreted / played by software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297720/term-for-frame-rate-when-reading-audio-data/297723#297723). Similar to how one uses a video's frame-rate to know how fast to present the frames.

This seems to meet the criteria, but a user downvoted my question and linked to a meta discussion:

[On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

I read that meta question and its accepted answer, and it clarifies that questions asking "what should I name this" are off topic, but "what is the name of this well known concept?" Is on-topic.

My question, being "What is the term for the rate at which audio data should be read?" isn't really a code problem, it's a matter of well known terminology, and seems to fit the criteria set by the community through the "terminology" tag and meta duscussions. So why has this user downvoted and linked to meta on my question? It also recieved close votes.

Subsequently, my question recieved a perfect answer quickly, it was "Sampling Rate"

Answer (score 4):

Down votes do not only signal on-topic or off topics.  The mouseover for the down vote of a question reads:

> This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful

(emphasis mine)

Search for [frame rate audio](https://www.google.com/search?q=frame+rate+audio) produces a number of hits.  For me, I see:

> [image: frame rate audio]

While not the first, nor even the second - the answer to your question is on the first page of the google results.

If you were to do a slightly less specific search, it becomes the top result.

> [image: rate audio file]

When the term you are looking for shows up on the first page of google results when searching for the title of the question, it is fairly clear that no research was done prior to asking the question.