# I suggested an edit to clarify a question. Why was my edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The other day, I came across this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337857/name-for-a-list-whose-structure-is-only-defined-by-the-structure-of-the-elements

I saw that the question was on hold for being unclear. However, I felt like I clearly understood the question being asked, so I submitted an [edit suggestion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/155842) to make the question clearer. I was hoping that the edit would be accepted, the question would be reopened, and then I could post an answer.

My suggestion was rejected, and I don't understand why.

One reviewer selected this reason for rejecting the suggestion:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

My edit was, in fact, an attempt at improving the question, not an attempt at communicating with the author of the question. I don't understand why the reviewer would have thought I was intending to address the author.

Another reviewer selected this reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

In my opinion, my edit makes the question a lot clearer. Am I wrong about this?

Why was my edit rejected? I'd still like to salvage the original author's question somehow; is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The close reason of unclear isn't really accurate. This question is [primarily opinion based, since it's a name this thing question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6582/4). The edit does not resolve the reasons for closing the question and make it into a question that would be reopened, so rejecting the edits is appropriate to prevent the question from being bumped back to the homepage.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I think that the original question is a "what is the name of this well-known concept?" question, and since the concept does, in fact, *have* a name, it's not really opinion-based. But I accept the decision that was made. Thank you for your answer!