# Questions linked by meta questions shouldn't be permanently deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, meta

I recently asked [a question about terminology/'is there a name for this'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390181/is-there-a-term-that-refers-to-the-bundle-of-actions-action-creators-reducers) that was promptly deleted.

So then I looked on the software engineering meta to see 'are questions about terminology on topic?'.

And we get this question:

[Where to ask about IT terminology?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8881/where-to-ask-about-it-terminology)

Well asked question, with a good answer - and the question that he asked, now 404s - which makes the meta question a little harder to understand.

It should be easy enough to archive delete questions without permanently deleting them.

Does this functionality already exist?

Comment: The functionality is there, from a certain point of view.  If you have 10,000 or more reputation you'll have the [privilege](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to be able to [view deleted posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: I have updated the question you refer to with a screenshot of the deleted question.

Answer (score 6):

You point to a valid problem, but the solution cannot be to interfere with normal moderation or cleanup activities like deleting a question.

The actual problem here is that the Meta question relied on an *external link*. External links may provide additional context for a question, but the question should be able to stand on its own. Admittedly this is difficult for Meta questions about specific posts on the main site, but if some aspect of the post is integral to the Meta question then the asker could quote excerpts of the post, or post a screenshot.

If you later find a post that references a post that has been deleted in the meanwhile, you can go to our chatroom [The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard) and ask a 10k user (like me) to make the screenshot for you.