# Are questions asking for names of [anti-]patterns really off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[The question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/444588/what-is-the-anti-pattern-for-modules-that-group-objects-of-the-same-type) essentially asks: "Here's this bad thing I've noticed. It seems like an anti-pattern. Is it a recognized anti-pattern? What is it called?"

It was closed as "opinion-based".

Are questions about recognizing [anti-]patterns really considered opinion-based and therefore off-topic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

Comment: @gnat yes but it contradicts reality: it says "What is the name of this well-known concept?" is on-topic, when that's the question that was closed.

Comment: nothing in the question you describe suggests that it is about a well-known concept; rather opposite - it explicitly states that asker is  unaware of whether it is known or not: "Is it a recognized anti-pattern?"

Comment: @gnat do you know the concept?

Comment: @user253751: the one answer to your question told you already: there is nothing like *a  concept* for what you described there, at least there is commonly accepted name. Now we can all invent a lot of fancy new names for it, but most kind of misdesigns are worth an individual, fancy name. We close such kind of questions here rigirously because we made the experience in the past if we don't,  such questions will attract wild guesses or creative term inventions as answers.

Comment: ... Note also your question does not look like it will be deleted soon, it will probably stay as it is. It got one answer essentially saying "no named pattern here", which should be enough here. If your question would have been off-topic (which it is not, it is just too opinionated), it would have probably been deleted in between.

Comment: ... sorry, two typos, I meant "at least there is **no** commonly accepted name" above, and "most kind of misdesigns are **not** worth an individual, fancy name."

Answer (score 4):

It's important to realize that opinion-based does not mean off-topic. There are plenty of questions where the subject matter is very much within the scope of this site, but they are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. Questions, like asking for the name of a design pattern, are in this category. There are plenty of on-topic questions about architectural and design patterns. However, asking us to name it tends to yield many people sharing their opinion on a possible name rather than a canonical name, if one exists. This type of question then turns into a popularity contest rather than one where answers can be judged based on their correctness.